# Discord I Can't Find A Way To Make A On Join Member Message

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, discord.py

I have been trying to make a member on join message in discord.py **(Rewrite)**
I get an error. First my command is below.

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
guild = member.guild
channel = (553090886683197451)
message ='Hello {}, Welcome to {} Discord server, We hope u good day at our server. Also please read the rules carefully'.format(member.mention, guild.name)
await user.send(channel, message)
```

The error is below

```
line 15, in on_member_join
await user.send(channel, message)
NameError: name 'user' is not defined
```

i want my bot to send message to a specific channel and the message which i have written above. of anybody could help it would be great!.

Comment: What do you expect this to do? You either want to do `await member.send(message)` to send a private message to the user, or `await member.guild.get_channel(channel).send(message)` to send the message to some announcements channel.

Comment: Thankyou sir, but i have found the solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike the async version, you have to first find the channel using the `get_channel()` method

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = bot.get_channel(553090886683197451)
    guild=member.guild
    message ='Hello {}, Welcome to {} Discord server, We hope u good day at our server. Also please read the rules carefully'.format(member.mention, guild.name)
    await channel.send(message)
```

And as Patric Haugh mentioned you'd do `member.send()` to private message